# Connect to AWS RDS with python with IAM Database Authentication

Tags: python, amazon-iam, rds

I would like to connect to RDS with python with IAM Database Authentication.

I can find how to connect to RDS with IAM SSL certification or how to connect to RDS with psycopg2.

But I cannot find how to connect to RDS with python with IAM Database Authentication.

Is there any way to do that?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can do that just only to use psycopg2 with sslrootsert.
Thanks!